# How to iterate over dates (days/ hours/ months) inside the data pipeline using beam on cloud dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Greeting folks1

I Am trying to load data from GCS to BigQuery using Cloud Dataflow.

data inside the bucket are storing in the following structure

"bucket_name/user_id/date/date_hour_user_id.csv"

example "my_bucket/user_1262/2021-01-02/2021-01-02_18_user_id.csv"

if I have 5 users for example ["user_1262", "user_1263", "user_1264", "user_1265", "user_1266"]

and i wanna load to bq (1 hour of data) for all clients for example hour = "18" in a range of 1 week I wanna iterate over all

clients to get the file with the prefix 18 I have created this code but the iteration infect the data

pipeline for each moving from one client to another the code runs a new pipeline.

```
def run(argv=None):

  mydate=['2021-01-02 00:00:00', '2021-01-02 23:00:00'] 
  fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
  hour = dt.timedelta(hours=1)
  day = dt.timedelta(days=1)
  start_time,  end_time = [dt.datetime.strptime(d, fmt) for d in mydate]
  currdate = start_time

  cols = ['cols0','cols1']

  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="User Input Data .")
  args, beam_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)

  while currdate <= end_time:
  
    str_date = currdate.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
  
    str_hour = '%02d' % (int(currdate.strftime('%H')))
    
    

    print("********WE ARE PROCESSING FILE ON DATE ---> %s HOUR --> %s" % (str_date, str_hour))
    
    user_list = ["user_1262", "user_1263", "user_1264", "user_1265", "user_1266"]
    
    for user_id in user_list:
      
        file_path_user = "gs://user_id/%s/%s/%s_%s_%s.csv" % (user_id, str_date, str_date, str_hour, user_id)


        with beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions(beam_args)) as p:

            input_data = p | 'ReadUserfile' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(file_path_user_table, columns=cols)
            decode = input_data | 'decodeData' >> beam.ParDo(de_code())
            clean_data = decode | 'clean_dt' >> beam.Filter(clea_data)
            writetobq....
    currdate += day
run()
```

Comment: I don't fully understand what the question is. Are you trying to find a way to perform this iteration inside one pipeline, instead of creating a new pipeline for each iteration?

Comment: Yes exactly, iteration per day, the data pipeline works with each day files separately.

Comment: Will the pipeline run properly with multiple users' data? For example, if you used [textio.ReadAllFromText](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.29.0/apache_beam.io.textio.html#apache_beam.io.textio.ReadAllFromText) with a PCollection of every single input file, would the pipeline still work? If not, what else is different in each pipeline? Because at the moment the example code only shows the input file changing.

Comment: Yes that's what I need i need only to change the input files and directories, each directory name is a date and i want process data by date, so data still always separate by date.

Comment: Gotcha. I added an answer, let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can continue to generate a list of input files in your pipeline creation script. However instead of creating a new pipeline for each input file, you can put them into a list. Then make your pipeline begin with a [Create transform](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#creating-pcollection-in-memory) reading that list, followed by a [textio.ReadAllFromText](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.29.0/apache_beam.io.textio.html#apache_beam.io.textio.ReadAllFromText) transform. This will create a PCollection out of your list of files, and then begin reading from that list of files.